# Google Cast Android does not run smoothly when using local http url

Tags: android, localhost, chromecast, google-photos

My app integrates Google cast. The app is similar to Google Photos app. It allows user to browse files, then cast to chrome cast devices. Following this link: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android.

I setup local http url for my file like this: http://192.168.1.45:8989/local/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/AnyRestore/20200908_113828.mp4
Video can cast, but it is interrupted, lag even can't load the very big videos

I tried hardcoding to change the url look similar this one: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/BigBuckBunny.mp4 like sample app above. Magically it works.

I would like to know the issue is local http url can't cast, right?. And anyone can give me know Google Photos is using https like demo app or local http like me.

I also used to Youtube, Netflix to cast. It's can cast even app is closing or force close. But Google Photos is not, cast is stoped right away if close the app. Can you explain this?

Finally, I want implement google cast function for my app like Google Photos app. Please give me any suggest.